# Where are the 5 bottles?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I'm searching the 5 bottles in *The Legend of Zelda: A Link Between Worlds*, but I've just found the one in the empty house. Where are the other bottles?

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrased from the [Bottle](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Bottle#The_Legend_of_Zelda:_A_Link_Between_Worlds) page on the *Zelda* fandom wiki:

> - The Street Merchant in Kakariko Village for 100 Rupees.
> - The one given to Link by the Bird Lover hidden Under the bridge.
> - In a chest in the Vacant House (the Lorule counterpart to Link's house) by bombing a fragile wall on the back of the house.
> - Donate a total of 3,000 Rupees to the Great Rupee Fairy.
> - At the bottom of south-eastern Lake Hylia is a bottle containing a letter from the Bouldering Guy, who is stuck on Death Mountain. The note admonishes whomever finds it to bring him Premium Milk from Kakariko Village's Milk Bar. After he drinks it he gives you the bottle as thanks.